# How to create PropertyChangedEventHandler from method name

Tags: c#

I'm newbie in OO programing and C#, and I would need some help.

I have several methods that could possibly be called upon a PropertyChanged event from a class member.
A collection of that class is created based with data coming from a text file

I would like that the method to be called is also read from the text file like any other data (as string then).

How could I instanciate the event handlder and register to that event without giving the method as argument, but the method name instead, like:

```
var handler = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyHandler)
myData.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)handler;
```

I would like  to achieve something like:

```
string str = "MyHandler";
var handler = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(str)
myData.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)str;`
```

I know that this is not working, but I don't know where to look to find a solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Write one handler, with a switch on the string from the text file, where each switch case calls a different method. If all the methods named in the file have the same parameters and return type, you could use a `Dictionary<string, MyMethodType>`. Reflection is an option, but I wouldn't recommend it, because live data. But you could do reflection and write an Attribute that you put on any method that should be allowed to be called by this setup.

Comment: Will the chosen method change at runtime, or is it one and done?

Comment: I thought about the switch/case, but I was thinking that I it should be a better "standart" way. The method is chosen at startup by reading a file and will not change.

Comment: That's easy then. Isma's answer is your best approach. My suggestion above assumed that it'd be much more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using reflection to find the method and dynamically assign it to the delegate, something like:

```
public void AssignPropertyChangedMethod(string methodName)
{
    var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PropertyChangedEventHandler), this, methodInfo);
    myData.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)handler;
}
```

I haven't tested it myself so I am not sure it will work but maybe it will get you in the right direction.

Comment: It sounds like `AsignPropertyChangedEvent` doesn't need to be an event, and only happens once. If not, you could be accumulating a lot of handlers on `PropertyChanged`

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it to a method.

Comment: One more thing: Adding the handler should just be `myData.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)handler;`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the cast.

Comment: And you're going to want to pass `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance` to GetMethod() if it's not a public method. You should really have tested this answer, there was too much wrong with it.

Comment: I updated it again, thanks. you are right I should have tested it, but the question was not entirely clear so I just wanted to provide a quick answer first.

Comment: Great, it is working like I wanted to. Thanks. I'm just sorry i'm too newbie, I can't vote for your answer Isma.